# vector push_back throwing sigabrt error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using `std::vector::push_back` in a `for-loop` and the moment I add an if condition it starts giving an error.

```
if(p>0) a[p]->vec.push_back(i)
```

where `a` is structure containing a vector among other things.

The error does not seem to depend on the condition.

```
struct link
{
    vector<int>children;  
    int noOfchildren;  
     struct link * parent;  
}
typedef struck link * node;




for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
            a[i]=(node)malloc(sizeof(element));
            scanf("%d",&p);
            a[i]->parent=a[p];
            a[i]->noOfchildren=0;
            if(p>0)
            a[p]->children.push_back(i);

    }
```

a[0] is initialised earlier.

Comment: Please post more code.  How are `a` and `p` defined, initialized, and used?

Comment: Can you include some actual code?  There's not much we can do with just a description of your code.

Comment: Please include a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your code into your question. We're not mind readers; as of right now we are about as clueless as you are.

Comment: try `if(p>0 && a[p] != NULL) a[p]->vec.push_back(i);` But I can't say much more until I know if `a[p]` is even initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: By using `malloc` rather than `new` you are not constructing the node `a[i]`. Don't use `malloc` to allocate an instance of a C++ class.

Comment: you should check your return values especially functions that take input like `scanf`, what if p is -42 or some other random value? also why use `malloc` when you can use `new` - after all you tagged it C++

Comment: you loop from 1 to n, are you sure about this? normally arrays start at 0

Comment: i have made the edit that a[0] has been initialised earlier.

Comment: but how large did you declare a[] ?

Comment: I think Karoly has the right answer.

Comment: Whoever told you to use `malloc` gets no pudding this week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allocating *uninitialized* memory with `malloc`. Because of that, `children` is uninitialized too. Calling `push_back` on it is UB.

Use `a[i] = new link();`.

Comment: could u tell me syntax of how to use new in the above case